# Multiple inheritance based on flags

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have several classes, say `A`,`B`, and `C`, and corresponding flags `HAS_A=1`, `HAS_B=2`, and `HAS_C=4`. Is it possible to write a class in such a way that its parents (from `A`,`B`, and `C`) will be determined by a combination of these flags?

Example:

```
ParentsFromFlags<HAS_A | HAS_C> x;
// x ends up having the features of A and C
```

I know I can have variable multiple parents with `<typename... Parents>`, but I'd like this because I want to ensure that if `A`, `B`, and `C` are parents of the class, they will always appear in a certain order.

Comment: "... they will always appear in a certain order."  So `ParentsFromFlags<HAS_A & HAS_C>` and `ParentsFromFlags<HAS_C & HAS_A>` would be different?

Comment: No (with flags this would be impossible to differentiate). I simply want `A` be before `B` which in turn to be before `C`.

Comment: Sorry. I just now realized that I had typed `&` in the combination of flags instead of `|`. I fixed that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does the job, at the cost of introducing some extra class in the hierarcy...

```
enum ParentFlags { HAS_A = 1, HAS_B = 2, HAS_C = 4 };

class A{};
class B{};
class C{};

template <int M>
class ParentClass {};

template <>
class ParentClass<0>{};

template <>
class ParentClass<HAS_A> : public A {};

template <>
class ParentClass<HAS_B> : public B{};

template <>
class ParentClass<HAS_C> : public C{};

template <int F, int M>
class ParentTraits : public ParentClass<F & M>, 
                     public ParentTraits<F & ~M, M << 1>
{};

template <int M>
class ParentTraits<0, M>
{};

template <int F>
class ParentFromFlags : public ParentTraits<F, 1>
{
};

int main()
{
    ParentFromFlags<HAS_A | HAS_B> ab;
    ParentFromFlags<HAS_A | HAS_C> ac;
    ParentFromFlags<HAS_A | HAS_B | HAS_C> abc;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is wayyyy simpler than what I was trying to do. +1.

Comment: What is the `ParentClass<0>` specialization for?

Comment: @BorislavStanimirov Making the repeated-inheritance stop when you have no more inheritance to do. Note that it recurses to itself - if you have no end case your compiler will just error-out at 500 inheritances (of which 497 without point).

Comment: @dascandy ParentClass<0> is the same as ParentClass<M> ... it doesn't seem to change anything. You probably thought I was asking about the ParentTraits<0, M> partial specialization, which is used as an end condition

Comment: @BorislavStanimirov Yes. That specialization seems to do nothing, actually. I think he intended to leave class ParentClass as undefined, which would lead to compile errors if you forgot to extend it with a new class, which are now silently hidden.

Answer (score 4):

This is a little more generic than what you're looking for, but all you'd need now is to substitute `filtered_list` for a meta function that filters the classes based on your flags.

```
template<typename... T>
struct type_list;

template<typename T>
struct filtered_list;

template<typename T, typename... U>
struct filtered_list<type_list<T,U...>> {
    using type = type_list<U...>;
};

template<typename TypeList>
using filtered_list_t = typename filtered_list<TypeList>::type;

template<typename T>
struct collect_base_classes;

template<typename... T>
struct collect_base_classes<type_list<T...>> : public T... {};

struct A { void test_a() {} };
struct B { void test_b() {} };
struct C { void test_c() {} };

class Test : public collect_base_classes<filtered_list_t<type_list<A,B,C>>> {};

int main() {
    Test t;
    t.test_a(); //error, we dropped A from our base class list
    t.test_b();
    t.test_c();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way and an optimal way to solve this problem.

The easiest solution is to just use a compile-time type selector like [conditional_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional), combined with an empty-base class:

```
template <int M>
struct empty_base {};

template <int flags>
struct Foo 
    : std::conditional_t<flags & Has_A, A, empty_base<1>>
    , std::conditional_t<flags & Has_B, B, empty_base<2>>
    , std::conditional_t<flags & Has_C, C, empty_base<3>>
{
    int x;
};
```

The problem with this approach is that it won't be able to trigger the [empty base class optimization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) in C++, due to the use of multiple inheritance. As a result, the Foo values will be a single word larger than necessary.

You can solve this by chaining the bases in a way similar to what [boost.compressed_pair](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/utility/doc/html/compressed_pair.html) does:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
struct compressed_pair_of_bases: T1, T2 {};

template <class T1, int N>
struct compressed_pair_of_bases<T1, empty_base<N>>: T1 {};

template <bool Predicate, class T, class Next>
using predicated_parent_chain_t = typename std::conditional_t<Predicate,
    compressed_pair_of_bases<T, Next>,
    Next>;

template <int flags>
struct Bar :
    predicated_parent_chain_t<!!(flags & Has_A), A,
        predicated_parent_chain_t<!!(flags & Has_B), B,
            predicated_parent_chain_t<!!(flags & Has_C), C,
                empty_base<1>>>>
{
    int x;
};
```

This solution is able to completely optimize away the base types when they are not selected:

```
    std::cout << sizeof(Bar<0>); // prints 4 on a 32-bit target
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is what I ended up with. It's basically the same as [marom's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31850108/1453047), but a bit more readable (at least for me)

```
enum ParentFlags { HAS_A = 1, HAS_B = 2, HAS_C = 4 };

class A { int a; };
class B { int b[2]; };
class C { int c[3]; };

template <int Flags>
class ParentA {};

template <>
class ParentA<HAS_A> : public A
{};

template <int Flags, int ThisFlag = Flags & HAS_B>
class ParentB : public ParentA<Flags & ~HAS_B>
{};

template <int Flags>
class ParentB<Flags, HAS_B> : public ParentA<Flags & ~HAS_B>, public B
{};

template <int Flags, int ThisFlag = Flags & HAS_C>
class ParentC : public ParentB<Flags & ~HAS_C>
{};

template <int Flags>
class ParentC<Flags, HAS_C> : public ParentB<Flags & ~HAS_C>, public C
{
};

template <int Flags>
class ParentFromFlags : public ParentC<Flags>
{};
```